# Loading a progressbar before loading listview in a custom DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is that the progress spinner only loads once the api call is complete. I guess it makes sence cause only after that I return the View.
Im not sure how to add this to the Dialog before the and while the api call is being made?

```
protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    subscriptions = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
    final View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);

    header = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.channels_header,null);
    ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.channels_header)).setText("Channels"); 

    LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) vw.findViewById(R.id.channelsProgress);
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//        Do this in a new Thread

    final ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);

//        ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.channel_desciption)).setText("CHANNELS");
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//                      get the all the channels from api on web
                    channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET", null);
        }
    };

    thread.start(); 

    lv.addHeaderView(header);

    return vw;
}
```

channel_content_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/channels_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelsProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbChannelsProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is going to work but you can try to first create the dialog and then change the content!

This is ugly and can be easily rewritten with AsyncTask but I think it'll do the trick:

```
protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    subscriptions = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
    final View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);    
    LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) vw.findViewById(R.id.channelsProgress);
    linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.channels_header)).setText("Channels"); 

    //        Do this in a new Thread   
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//                      get the all the channels from api on web
                    channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET", null);
                    setListLayout(vw,linlaHeaderProgress);
        }
    };
    thread.start(); 



    return vw;
}


protected void setListLayout(View vw,View progressBar){


     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Thread.sleep(500); // to avoid super fast results from the server and always display the loader bar for a while
                    header = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.channels_header,null);    
                    final ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
                    lv.addHeaderView(header);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(hidden);
                    lv.setVisibility(visible);

                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. It could be that the Thread execution is too fast that it finishes off early before the Progress bar is displayed. I would hold the Thread in sleep mode to see if that is the case. **(This just to confirm what is going on not to use this method it will cause and extra delay)**

   For example try placing this:

   ```
     Thread thread = new Thread()
         {
             @Override
             public void run() {
             try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
             }
             catch(Exception e){}
     //                      get the all the channels from api on web
                         channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET", null);
             }
         };
   ```

   1. Also if the above doesn't works then try this below method of Shwoing the Progress Bar and see if it works:

   Call the showProgressBar() method from where you will create the instance of the Dialog Box or if not possible then start of the onCreateDialog Method:

   ```
     void showProgressBar(Context ctx){

       progressBar = new ProgressDialog(ctx);  //this is a context object probably ctx object will go here as 
       progressBar.setCancelable(false);
       progressBar.setMessage("Heavy Process....");
       progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

       progressBar.show();
       }

    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

       ///I think ctx is an Activity
       showProgressBar(ctx);  ///if it is not possible to call showProgressBar() from where you are instantiating the Dialog

        subscriptions = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater();
        final View vw = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channel_content_view, null);

        header = ((SettingsActivity) ctx).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.channels_header,null);
        ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.channels_header)).setText("Channels"); 

       /*
        Commented below lines of Progress Bar because we are displayin it above.
        */
        //LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) vw.findViewById(R.id.channelsProgress);
        ///linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //                 Do this in a new Thread

        final ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);

    //        ((TextView) lv.findViewById(R.id.channel_desciption)).setText("CHANNELS");

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {

       @Override
       public void run() {

    //                      get the all the channels from api on web

               channels = Json.getJson(apiurl + "/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET", null);

       }

        };



        thread.start(); 

        lv.addHeaderView(header);

        return vw;
    }
   ```

Also If you want to embedd the ProgressBar within the Dialog Box then you will have to create an Acivity and make that appear as a Dialog. To that simply add

Below Copied from Android Documentation page (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) :

Tip: If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity as a dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Simply create an activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in the  manifest element:

Note It is very easy most of the code in your onCreateDialogView is portable to Activity onCreate() method

Comment: The progress bar does show, but its behind the dialogview. how do I make it so its ontop?

Comment: @Harry That means you need a custom Dialog. Then you will have to make an Activity appear as a Dialog. I will update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a very simple issue with my layouts

cHanging my layout to : works

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/channels_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelsProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbChannelsProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```